# How to capture the values that were present at the time of calling asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
let x = "value before setTimeout";

function cb() {
    console.log(currentValue); 
}

setTimeout(cb, 3000);

x = "updated value";
```

How to print "value before setTimoeout" with the help of callback function. How to capture the old value and use it?

Comment: Your question title is confusing, because what you have *already* shows you the value as it stands when the asynchronous function (the timer callback) is called. I think what you're asking for is the value as it stood at the time the timer was initialized, *before* the callback function is invoked. There is no automated way of tracking the history of a variable, but you can implement something yourself, depending on what your application needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your callback function inside another one that will keep the `currentValue` in its closure so you can access it later.
The main difference is that your callback function has to be called once now (`cb(x)`) in order to bind that value.

```js
let x = "value before setTimeout";

function cb(currentValue) {
  return function() {
    console.log(currentValue);
    console.log(x);
  }
}

setTimeout(cb(x), 3000);

x = "updated value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it as a temporary coefficient:

```js
let a = 20

function log(a) {
  console.log('a is: ' + a)
}

setTimeout(log, 1000, a)

a = 43
```

Comment: is there any other way than this? without the help of settimeout function.

Comment: you can save the value history of the variable as you need to know how far the value you need is from the current value

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = "value before setTimeout";

function cb(val) {
  console.log(val);
}

setTimeout(cb, 3000, x);

x = "updated value";
```

By passing x as an argument to the callback function, you can capture its value at the time setTimeout is set, before it gets updated. And then print that captured value inside the callback.